# How to make "See All Item" button to pass data from RecyclerView to Another RecyclerView fragment - AndroidX

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, androidx

Q**uestion**

> I want to make the `"See All Item"` button to pass data from RecyclerView to Another RecyclerView fragment
>   it looks like play store that has the `"More"` button to see all item in another fragment

**AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews.java**

```
public class AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews> modelSectionHotTrendingNews;

public AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews(Context mContext, ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews> modelSectionHotTrendingNews) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.modelSectionHotTrendingNews = modelSectionHotTrendingNews;
}

@Override
public SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_section_hottrendingnews, null);
    return new SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder = (SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder) holder;
    ModelSectionHotTrendingNews modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX = modelSectionHotTrendingNews.get(position);

    //Set
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVSectionTitle.setText(modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.getHeaderTitle());

    ArrayList singleSectionItems = modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.getAllItemsInSection();
    /*AdapterSingleHotLatestNews.RecyclerViewClickListener listenerLatestNews;
    listenerLatestNews = new AdapterSingleHotLatestNews.RecyclerViewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRowHotLatestNewsClick(View view, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onIconHotLatestNewsClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    };*/
    AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews itemListDataAdapter = new AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews(mContext, singleSectionItems);

    /*itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events once again.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
            // Handle RecyclerView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });*/


    final String sectionTitle = modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.getHeaderTitle();
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.BTNHotTrendingNewsMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "click event on more, "+sectionTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


    /*Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.bg)
            .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/

    //SetRecyclerView
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int itemCount = modelSectionHotTrendingNews.size();
    return itemCount;
}

public class SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView TVSectionTitle;
    protected ImageView BTNHotTrendingNewsMore;
    protected RecyclerView RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews;

    public SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        TVSectionTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_SectionTitle);
        BTNHotTrendingNewsMore= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.BTN_HotTrendingNewsMore);
        RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView_Section_HotTrendingNews);
    }

}
```

}

**AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews.java**

```
public class AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews;

public AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews(Context mContext, ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.modelSingleHotTrendingNews = modelSingleHotTrendingNews;
}

//Container
@Override
public SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_single_hottrendingnews, null);
    return new SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(v);
}

//Fill Container with Model Setter Getter
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder = (SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder) holder;
    final ModelSingleHotTrendingNews modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX = modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position);

    //Set
    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVGameDate.setText(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGamedate());
    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVGameDescription.setText(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGamedescription());
    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGGameImage.setImageResource(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGameimage());



    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Boolean booltrendingnewssaving = modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getTrendingnewssaving();

            final int id = modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getId();

            if (booltrendingnewssaving == true){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn Off Saved News " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_off);
                modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.setTrendingnewssaving(false);
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, false);*/
            } else if(booltrendingnewssaving == false) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn On Saved News " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_on);
                modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.setTrendingnewssaving(true);
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, true);*/
            }
        }
    });



   /* Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.bg)
            .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/

    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedescription(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Passing Data to GameDescriptionActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GameDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ImagePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGameimage());
            intent.putExtra("NamePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedate());
            intent.putExtra("UrlPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getId());
            intent.putExtra("DescriptionPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedescription());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int itemCount = modelSingleHotTrendingNews.size();
    return itemCount;
}

public class SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView TVGameDate;
    TextView TVGameDescription;
    ImageView IMGGameImage;

    ImageView ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving;
    private RelativeLayout ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer;


    public SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        TVGameDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_GameDate);
        TVGameDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_GameDescription);
        IMGGameImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_GameImage);

        ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ICON_HotTrendingNewsSaving);
        ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ROW_HotTrendingNewsContainer);
    }

}
```

**ModelSectionHotTrendingNews.java**

```
public class ModelSectionHotTrendingNews {

private String headerTitle;
private ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> allItemsInSection;

public ModelSectionHotTrendingNews() {
}

public String getHeaderTitle() {
    return headerTitle;
}

public void setHeaderTitle(String headerTitle) {
    this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
}

public ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> getAllItemsInSection() {
    return allItemsInSection;
}

public void setAllItemsInSection(ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> allItemsInSection) {
    this.allItemsInSection = allItemsInSection;
}
```

}

**ModelSingleHotTrendingNews.java**

```
public class ModelSingleHotTrendingNews {

private int id;
private String gamedate;
private String gamedescription;
private int gameimage;

private Boolean trendingnewssaving;
private String value;
private String message;

public ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(int id, String gamedate, String gamedescription, int gameimage, Boolean trendingnewssaving, String value, String message) {
    this.id = id;
    this.gamedate = gamedate;
    this.gamedescription = gamedescription;
    this.gameimage = gameimage;
    this.trendingnewssaving = trendingnewssaving;
    this.value = value;
    this.message = message;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getGamedate() {
    return gamedate;
}

public void setGamedate(String gamedate) {
    this.gamedate = gamedate;
}

public String getGamedescription() {
    return gamedescription;
}

public void setGamedescription(String gamedescription) {
    this.gamedescription = gamedescription;
}

public int getGameimage() {
    return gameimage;
}

public void setGameimage(int gameimage) {
    this.gameimage = gameimage;
}

public Boolean getTrendingnewssaving() {
    return trendingnewssaving;
}

public void setTrendingnewssaving(Boolean trendingnewssaving) {
    this.trendingnewssaving = trendingnewssaving;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

}

**FragmentFunction**

```
public void createDummyData1() {
    ModelSectionHotTrendingNews modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX = new ModelSectionHotTrendingNews();
    modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.setHeaderTitle("TRENDING NEWS");

    ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews = new ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews>();
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(1, "20 Mei 2019", "sdfjiaOIJdosjfsjdfjsoid", R.drawable.kleptocats, false, "x53535", "No Error"));
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(2, "21 Mei 2019", "sdfjiaOIJdosjfsjdfjsoid", R.drawable.kleptocats, false, "x53535", "No Error"));
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(3, "22 Mei 2019", "sdfjiaOIJdosjfsjdfjsoid", R.drawable.kleptocats, false, "x53535", "No Error"));
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(4, "23 Mei 2019", "sdfjiaOIJdosjfsjdfjsoid", R.drawable.kleptocats, false, "x53535", "No Error"));
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(5, "24 Mei 2019", "sdfjiaOIJdosjfsjdfjsoid", R.drawable.kleptocats, false, "x53535", "No Error"));
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(6, "25 Mei 2019", "sdfjiaOIJdosjfsjdfjsoid", R.drawable.kleptocats, false, "x53535", "No Error"));
    modelSingleHotTrendingNews.add(new ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(7, "26 Mei 2019", "sdfjiaOIJdosjfsjdfjsoid", R.drawable.kleptocats, false, "x53535", "No Error"));


    modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.setAllItemsInSection(modelSingleHotTrendingNews);
    modelSectionHotTrendingNews.add(modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX);
}
```

//UPDATED
I Added this on SectionAdapterTabHot.java
I use same model but different RecyclerView and Adapter like: RecyclerViewMoreSection/SingleTabHot and Section/SingleMoreAdapterTabHot.java

```
final String sectionTitle = modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.getHeaderTitle();
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.BTNHotTrendingNewsMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "click event on more, "+sectionTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews.setAdapter( new AdapterMoreSingleHotTrendingNews(v.getContext(), modelSectionHotTrendingNews.get(position).getAllItemsInSection()));
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, TabMoreHotActivity.class);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

//SectionAdapterViewHolder

```
public class SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView TVSectionTitle;
    protected ImageView BTNHotTrendingNewsMore;
    protected RecyclerView RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews;
    protected RecyclerView RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews;

    public SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        TVSectionTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_SectionTitle);
        BTNHotTrendingNewsMore= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.BTN_HotTrendingNewsMore);
        RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView_Section_HotTrendingNews);
        RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewMore_Section_HotTrendingNews);
    }

}
```

//This is the problem I want to Access RecyclerViewMoreHotTrendingNews in itemmore_hot but it doesn't founded in item_hot

```
@Override
public SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_section_hottrendingnews, null);
    return new SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(v);
}
```

//This is TabMoreHotActivity.java

```
public class TabMoreHotActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//1
ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews> modelSectionHotTrendingNews = new ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews>();
AdapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews adapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews;

//ModelData
List<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragmentmore_tabhot);


    //1
    RecyclerView RecyclerViewMoreSingleHotTrendingNews = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewMore_Single_HotTrendingNews);
    RecyclerViewMoreSingleHotTrendingNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews = new AdapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews(this, modelSectionHotTrendingNews);
    RecyclerViewMoreSingleHotTrendingNews.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    RecyclerViewMoreSingleHotTrendingNews.setAdapter(adapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews);
    //Optimized
    RecyclerViewMoreSingleHotTrendingNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerViewMoreSingleHotTrendingNews.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
}
```

}

//But I got This error when I click "See All Item" button

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.indofun.android.indojoy, PID: 11456
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference
    at com.indofun.android.indojoy.Adapters.Adapter_HotTrendingNews.AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews$1.onClick(AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews.java:88)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6891)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26083)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: It would be better to share some code or the command you've used.

Comment: I already updated the code that I use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From First Adapter `onClick`, call second adapter and update RecyclerView

```
sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.BTNHotTrendingNewsMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews.setAdapter( new AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews(v.getContext(), modelSectionHotTrendingNews.get(position).getAllItemsInSection()))
        }
    });
```

Or if you want to show this **More News** in another activity. Then do this:

1. Make **`ModelSingleHotTrendingNews`** class `Serializable` like this:

   public class ModelSingleHotTrendingNews implements Serializable {
       ...
   }
2. Change `onClick`

   sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.BTNHotTrendingNewsMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, TabMoreHotActivity.class);
                   Intent().putExtra("MoreNews", modelSectionHotTrendingNews.get(position).getAllItemsInSection())
                   mContext.startActivity(intent);
               }
           });
3. In `TabMoreHotActivity` use ArrayList instead of `ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews>`

hope this will help you. You made your code mess :(

Comment: I already added that function, and got an error message when I click the "See All Items" Button, what should I do?

Comment: You initialize those `RecyclerView` in `SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder` class. Check there why that null

Comment: What does **`TabMoreHotActivity`** do? Where you show more News another `RecyclerView` within same activity or different activity?

Comment: I want to Access RecyclerViewMoreHotTrendingNews in itemmore_section_hot.xml but it doesn't founded in item_section_hot.xml, my purpose is to user RecyclerViewMoreHotTrendingNews in MoreTabHotActivity, that's why I added this: sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews.setAdapter( new AdapterMoreSingleHotTrendingNews(v.getContext(), modelSectionHotTrendingNews.get(position).getAllItemsInSection()));, I updated my description code you can check it out

Comment: I don't what is the best way to pass RecyclerView to another RecyclerView, Fragment or Activity, but right now I use another Activity

Comment: Why you pass `RecyclerView`? Just pass data and add `RecyclerView` there with this data.

Comment: I added this in TabMoreHotActivity, Error when using getStringArrayList>> ArrayList test;
        test = intent.getExtras().getStringArrayList("MoreNews");
        adapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews = new AdapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews(this, test);

Comment: it still got error, null in getItemCount AdapterMoreSection, I added function same as your instructed, ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews> modelSectionHotTrendingNews;
        modelSectionHotTrendingNews = (ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(
                "MoreNews");
        adapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews = new AdapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews(this, modelSectionHotTrendingNews);

Answer (score 1):

You can create listeners in the Recyclers parent.
When some data from one recycler will be changed, trigger your listener in the current adapter after that your parent receives it and will trigger some updating method in the second recycler adapter.

But for sure it will be better if you provide some code or more detailed description.