# Why I cannot pass data from RecyclerView to another RecyclerView - AndroidX

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, androidx, serializable

I want to make data from RecyclerView1 Activity1 can be passed to RecyclerView2 Activity2

//SectionAdapter.java

```
public class AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews> modelSectionHotTrendingNews;

public AdapterSectionHotTrendingNews(Context mContext, ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews> modelSectionHotTrendingNews) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.modelSectionHotTrendingNews = modelSectionHotTrendingNews;
}

@Override
        public SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_section_hottrendingnews, null);
    return new SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder = (SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder) holder;
    ModelSectionHotTrendingNews modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX = modelSectionHotTrendingNews.get(position);

    //Set
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVSectionTitle.setText(modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.getHeaderTitle());

    ArrayList singleSectionItems = modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.getAllItemsInSection();
    /*AdapterSingleHotLatestNews.RecyclerViewClickListener listenerLatestNews;
    listenerLatestNews = new AdapterSingleHotLatestNews.RecyclerViewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRowHotLatestNewsClick(View view, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onIconHotLatestNewsClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    };*/
    AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews itemListDataAdapter = new AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews(mContext, singleSectionItems);

    /*itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events once again.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
            // Handle RecyclerView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });*/


    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.BTNHotTrendingNewsMore.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, TabMoreHotActivity.class);
                // here you create put extra in new intent not the intent that you created

                intent.putExtra("MoreNews", modelSectionHotTrendingNews.get(position).getAllItemsInSection());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

            } });




    /*Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.bg)
            .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/

    //SetRecyclerView
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);
    sectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int itemCount = modelSectionHotTrendingNews.size();
    return itemCount;
}

public class SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView TVSectionTitle;
    protected ImageView BTNHotTrendingNewsMore;
    protected RecyclerView RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews;
    protected RecyclerView RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews;

    public SectionHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        TVSectionTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_SectionTitle);
        BTNHotTrendingNewsMore= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.BTN_HotTrendingNewsMore);
        RecyclerViewSectionHotTrendingNews = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView_Section_HotTrendingNews);
        RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewMore_Section_HotTrendingNews);
    }

}
```

}

//SingleAdapter.java

```
public class AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews;

public AdapterSingleHotTrendingNews(Context mContext, ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.modelSingleHotTrendingNews = modelSingleHotTrendingNews;
}

//Container
@Override
public SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_single_hottrendingnews, null);
    return new SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(v);
}

//Fill Container with Model Setter Getter
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder = (SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder) holder;
    final ModelSingleHotTrendingNews modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX = modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position);

    //Set
    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVGameDate.setText(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGamedate());
    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVGameDescription.setText(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGamedescription());
    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGGameImage.setImageResource(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGameimage());



    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Boolean booltrendingnewssaving = modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getTrendingnewssaving();

            final int id = modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getId();

            if (booltrendingnewssaving == true){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn Off Saved News " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_off);
                modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.setTrendingnewssaving(false);
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, false);*/
            } else if(booltrendingnewssaving == false) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn On Saved News " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_on);
                modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.setTrendingnewssaving(true);
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, true);*/
            }
        }
    });



   /* Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.bg)
            .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/

    singleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedescription(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Passing Data to GameDescriptionActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GameDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ImagePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGameimage());
            intent.putExtra("NamePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedate());
            intent.putExtra("UrlPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getId());
            intent.putExtra("DescriptionPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedescription());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int itemCount = modelSingleHotTrendingNews.size();
    return itemCount;
}

public class SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView TVGameDate;
    TextView TVGameDescription;
    ImageView IMGGameImage;

    ImageView ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving;
    private RelativeLayout ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer;


    public SingleHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        TVGameDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_GameDate);
        TVGameDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_GameDescription);
        IMGGameImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_GameImage);

        ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ICON_HotTrendingNewsSaving);
        ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ROW_HotTrendingNewsContainer);
    }

}
```

}

//ModelSection.java

```
public class ModelSectionHotTrendingNews implements Serializable {

private String headerTitle;
private ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> allItemsInSection;

public ModelSectionHotTrendingNews() {
}

public String getHeaderTitle() {
    return headerTitle;
}

public void setHeaderTitle(String headerTitle) {
    this.headerTitle = headerTitle;
}

public ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> getAllItemsInSection() {
    return allItemsInSection;
}

public void setAllItemsInSection(ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> allItemsInSection) {
    this.allItemsInSection = allItemsInSection;
}
```

}

//ModelSingle.java

```
public class ModelSingleHotTrendingNews implements Serializable {

private int id;
private String gamedate;
private String gamedescription;
private int gameimage;

private Boolean trendingnewssaving;
private String value;
private String message;

public ModelSingleHotTrendingNews(int id, String gamedate, String gamedescription, int gameimage, Boolean trendingnewssaving, String value, String message) {
    this.id = id;
    this.gamedate = gamedate;
    this.gamedescription = gamedescription;
    this.gameimage = gameimage;
    this.trendingnewssaving = trendingnewssaving;
    this.value = value;
    this.message = message;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getGamedate() {
    return gamedate;
}

public void setGamedate(String gamedate) {
    this.gamedate = gamedate;
}

public String getGamedescription() {
    return gamedescription;
}

public void setGamedescription(String gamedescription) {
    this.gamedescription = gamedescription;
}

public int getGameimage() {
    return gameimage;
}

public void setGameimage(int gameimage) {
    this.gameimage = gameimage;
}

public Boolean getTrendingnewssaving() {
    return trendingnewssaving;
}

public void setTrendingnewssaving(Boolean trendingnewssaving) {
    this.trendingnewssaving = trendingnewssaving;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

}

//AdapterMoreSection.java

```
public class AdapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews> modelSectionHotTrendingNews;

public AdapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews(Context mContext, ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews> modelSectionHotTrendingNews) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.modelSectionHotTrendingNews = modelSectionHotTrendingNews;
}

@Override
public SectionMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemmore_section_hottrendingnews, null);
    return new SectionMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(v);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final SectionMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder sectionMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder = (SectionMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder) holder;
    ModelSectionHotTrendingNews modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX = modelSectionHotTrendingNews.get(position);

    //Set
    sectionMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVSectionTitle.setText(modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.getHeaderTitle());
    ArrayList singleMoreSectionItems = modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.getAllItemsInSection();

    /*AdapterSingleHotLatestNews.RecyclerViewClickListener listenerLatestNews;
    listenerLatestNews = new AdapterSingleHotLatestNews.RecyclerViewClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRowHotLatestNewsClick(View view, int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onIconHotLatestNewsClick(View view, int position) {

        }
    };*/
    AdapterMoreSingleHotTrendingNews itemListDataAdapter = new AdapterMoreSingleHotTrendingNews(mContext, singleMoreSectionItems);

    /*itemRowHolder.recycler_view_list.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events once again.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
            // Handle RecyclerView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });*/


    final String sectionTitle = modelSectionHotTrendingNewsX.getHeaderTitle();
    sectionMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.BTNHotTrendingNewsMore.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override public void onClick(View v) {
                    //More IN RecyclerViewMore
                }
            });


    /*Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.bg)
            .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/

    //SetRecyclerView
    sectionMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
    sectionMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    sectionMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews.setAdapter(itemListDataAdapter);
    sectionMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int itemCount = modelSectionHotTrendingNews.size();
    return itemCount;
}

public class SectionMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView TVSectionTitle;
    protected ImageView BTNHotTrendingNewsMore;
    protected RecyclerView RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews;

    public SectionMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        TVSectionTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_SectionTitle);
        BTNHotTrendingNewsMore= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.BTN_HotTrendingNewsMore);
        RecyclerViewMoreSectionHotTrendingNews = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewMore_Section_HotTrendingNews);
    }

}
```

}

//AdapterMoreSingle.java

```
public class AdapterMoreSingleHotTrendingNews extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews;

public AdapterMoreSingleHotTrendingNews(Context mContext, ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.modelSingleHotTrendingNews = modelSingleHotTrendingNews;
}

//Container
@Override
public SingleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemmore_single_hottrendingnews, null);
    return new SingleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(v);
}

//Fill Container with Model Setter Getter
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final SingleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder singleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder = (SingleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder) holder;
    final ModelSingleHotTrendingNews modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX = modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position);

    //Set
    singleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVGameDate.setText(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGamedate());
    singleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.TVGameDescription.setText(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGamedescription());
    singleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.IMGGameImage.setImageResource(modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getGameimage());



    singleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Boolean booltrendingnewssaving = modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getTrendingnewssaving();

            final int id = modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.getId();

            if (booltrendingnewssaving == true){
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn Off Saved News " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                singleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_off);
                modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.setTrendingnewssaving(false);
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, false);*/
            } else if(booltrendingnewssaving == false) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Turn On Saved News " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                singleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_on);
                modelSingleHotTrendingNewsX.setTrendingnewssaving(true);
                /*updateSavedNewsSaving("update_newssaving", id, true);*/
            }
        }
    });



   /* Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(feedItem.getImageURL())
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.bg)
            .into(feedListRowHolder.thumbView);*/

    singleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder.ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedescription(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            //Passing Data to GameDescriptionActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GameDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ImagePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGameimage());
            intent.putExtra("NamePKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedate());
            intent.putExtra("UrlPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getId());
            intent.putExtra("DescriptionPKG",  modelSingleHotTrendingNews.get(position).getGamedescription());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    int itemCount = modelSingleHotTrendingNews.size();
    return itemCount;
}

public class SingleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView TVGameDate;
    TextView TVGameDescription;
    ImageView IMGGameImage;

    ImageView ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving;
    private RelativeLayout ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer;


    public SingleMoreHotTrendingNewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        TVGameDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_GameDate);
        TVGameDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TV_GameDescription);
        IMGGameImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.IMG_GameImage);

        ICONHotTrendingNewsSaving = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ICON_HotTrendingNewsSaving);
        ROWHotTrendingNewsContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ROW_HotTrendingNewsContainer);
    }

}
```

}

//Activity2More.java

```
public class TabMoreHotActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragmentmore_tabhot);

    AdapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews adapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews;
    ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews> modelSectionHotTrendingNews = new ArrayList<>();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null)
    {
        modelSectionHotTrendingNews = (ArrayList<ModelSectionHotTrendingNews>) bundle.getSerializable("MoreNews");
    }


    //1
    RecyclerView RecyclerViewMoreSingleHotTrendingNews = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerViewMore_Single_HotTrendingNews);
    RecyclerViewMoreSingleHotTrendingNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews = new AdapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews(this, modelSectionHotTrendingNews);

    RecyclerViewMoreSingleHotTrendingNews.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    RecyclerViewMoreSingleHotTrendingNews.setAdapter(adapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews);




    //Optimized
    RecyclerViewMoreSingleHotTrendingNews.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerViewMoreSingleHotTrendingNews.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
}
```

}

//Error

```
Process: com.indofun.android.indojoy, PID: 18827
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.indofun.android.indojoy.Models.Model_HotTrendingNews.ModelSingleHotTrendingNews cannot be cast to com.indofun.android.indojoy.Models.Model_HotTrendingNews.ModelSectionHotTrendingNews
    at com.indofun.android.indojoy.Adapters.AdapterMore_HotTrendingNews.AdapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews.onBindViewHolder(AdapterMoreSectionHotTrendingNews.java:39)
```

//NOTE
//RecyclerView1 using AdapterSection.java,AdapterSingle.java,ModelSection.java,ModelSingle.java
//RecyclerView2 using AdapterMoreSection.java,AdapterMoreSingle.java,ModelSection.java,ModelSingle.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside **`TabMoreHotActivity`** use like this:

```
    ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews> modelSingleHotTrendingNews = new ArrayList<>(); 
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(bundle!=null { 
        modelSingleHotTrendingNews = ArrayList<ModelSingleHotTrendingNews>) bundle.getSerializable("MoreNews");
    }
```

Comment: I told you the solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58318457/2637449. You sould accept the answer there as you change your code accordingly. Moreover you cast wrong model there thats why this exception arise here.

Comment: Mark the both answer Accepted